# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wavesplatform

I have  tried to install waves on Ubuntu 18.04LTS
link for installing waves in ubuntu : https://docs.waves.tech/en/waves-node/how-to-install-a-node/on-ubuntu

command:  sudo apt install waves

And I got this error

**Error:System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.**

and i also get same error when I use commands like:

1. sudo service waves.service start
2. sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/waves_1.2.17_all.deb
3. sudo dpkg -i waves_1.2.17_all.deb
4. sudo systemctl start waves.service

And if I use command according to this link: https://linuxhandbook.com/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd/

command : sudo service waves.service start

then it gives error:

**Error: waves.service: unrecognized service**

can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: can anyone help with it?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu on Windows? WSL?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. so ubuntu on Windows

Answer (score 2):

WSL doesn't support systemd and so:

```
systemctl .....
```

won't work

Instead use service and so:

```
sudo service waves start
```

Comment: Error: waves: unrecognized service

Comment: I suspect you have no file named waves in /etc/init.d

Comment: Can you tell me how can I solve this problem? i am just newbie

Comment: Future occurrence: I ran into the problem lately, the solution did not work and this helped me out: https://gist.github.com/alyleite/ca8b10581dbecd722d9dcc35b50d9b2b?permalink_comment_id=4008968